# How do I 'disable' my contextual filter (return all results) for uid=1?

Tags: views

I have a View (content) created with a contextual filter.
The contextual (Content:Country) filter uses PHP code to check custom fields:

```
global $user;
$user_uid = user_load($user->uid);
$mycountry = $user_uid->field_user_country['und']['0']['tid'];
return $mycountry;
```

The filter is [field_address_country] == [field_user_country]
The contextual filter works fine.

However, I would like to 'disable' the filer for admin (uid=1) so that I can view all nodes regardless of the field_address_country value.

I have tried adding a condition to check for uid=1 but it doesn't work

```
global $user;
$user_uid = user_load($user->uid);
$mycountry = $user_uid->field_user_country['und']['0']['tid'];
if ($user_uid == '1') {return 'all';}
else {return $mycountry;};
```

Is there a method for returning all results (or disabling the filter) for admin user?

Comment: Strange.  What does it return when you do a 'drupal_set_message()) statement on the $user_uid before returning?

Comment: What do you mean by "..a drupal_set_message()) statement on the $user_uid.." ?